# How to solve NumberFormatException

Tags: java, swing, oop

I am building a simple application. When I click on the button, dialog shows up, I fill up information and It converts into JTable. That is pretty much the whole program. When I try to put the info into the table, the exception pops out. Data seem to be with the correct data type as in the constructor.

**BUTTON LISTENER**

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==b_pridej){
            dialog = new MistoDialog();
            dialog.setVisible(true);

            mista.pridejMisto(dialog.getNoveMisto());
        }

    }
};
```

**THE METHOD WHICH FILLS THE CONSTRUCTOR WITH DATA FROM THE DIALOG**

```
public Misto getNoveMisto(){
            Misto misto = new Misto( new Integer(souradnice.getText()), nazev.getText(), poznamka.getText(),new Integer(hodnoceni.getText()),datum.getText());
            return misto;
        }
```

**CONSTRUCTOR**

```
public Misto(int souradnice, String nazev, String poznamka, int hodnoceni,String date) {
    this.souradnice = souradnice;
    this.nazev = nazev;
    this.poznamka = poznamka;
    this.hodnoceni = hodnoceni;
    this.date = date;
}
```

Comment: The stacktrace might be helpful

Comment: No, the error message would be *essential*, but surely Tomas searched on this error, and would know this.

Comment: the problem is that the exception is thrown before I even fill up the JTextFields, so It doesn't know the format of the text yet... @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: The problem is that you've **still** not shown your stacktrace (why?) and have not indicated which line throws the NFE (again, why?).

Comment: Is your dialog a **modal** JDialog? If not, then that's your problem. Make it modal.

Comment: check not  typical characters in string, check decimal point (comma/dot), often problem for polish deployment. Convert with Locale (ofiicial way), without locale but replace dot/comma, real life

Comment: this solved my problem, make it an answer if you want, thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: A better overall approach to this is to offer the user a `JSpinner` with a `SpinnerNumberModel`. Once the user has chosen a value, call `spinnerNumberModel.getNumber().intValue()` and the job is done..